# Why does this work? Being able to use a function from standard libraries by declaring the prototype without including the headers

Tags: c, gcc

I've been playing around my code editor and accidentally made this. This compiles fine, and works as intended. For additional context, I'm using GCC on Debian 11. As for how I knew the prototypes, VS Code's IntelliSense told me.

Why does it work, and how? Neither `<stdio.h>` nor `<math.h>` is included.

```
double pow(double _x, double _y);
int printf(const char *__restrict__ __format, ...);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", pow(2, -1));
}
```

Output: `0.500000`

Comment: Including a file is same as pasting its contents. (Almost.)

Comment: "without including the library" That is not true. Including a header is totally different from including a library. The header only tells the compiler what it may find elsewhere. It is like an IKEA catalog. You see all the stuff with names and details but you still need to get it from the store. It's task of the library to provide the implemtation of all those functions. If you really had not included the library, you would have been error messages from the linker about undefined references.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your functions like you did or by including the relevant header file(s) (preferred).  gcc will link in the definitions found in libc unless you tell it not to (with `-nolibc`)

Answer (score 2):

It works because the C standard explicitly requires it to work.

> [7.1.4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p2) Provided that a library function can be declared without reference to any type defined in a header, it is also permissible to declare the function and use it without including its associated header.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library is linked into most C projects. If you created a standard project, your IDE most likely took care of that part for you in the background.

Depending on how the compiler is configured, it may drag the functions in from the libc if they are defined as well. This allows a bit of optimization.

The header files tell your program how to access those functions. If the library is linked, then all of its functions are there, whether the header file is or not. You didn't magically bypass anything or anything like that. You just provided an alternative declaration of the function.

Comment: If you incluse a header, prototypes inside it are pasted into your code, and it says those functions exist, they'll be available on linking. If they aren't, you'll get a linker error. Compilers automatically include libc by default, you have it to specify if you don't want to. Since your prototypes match linked function in libc, there's no problem. If it wasn't a libc prototype but a custom lib, you'd have to link the lib yourself, `undefined reference` otherwise, you said function exists but it was not found while putting objects together, a part of the binary was missing.

Comment: @AR7CORE I probably should have been a bit more clear in my response. The OP's code snipit included manually declaring the function. That is why their version works without the header.